# Solve DE system: $ x' = y^{-2} , y' = - \sqrt {(t+1)^2- y^{-4}} $ Profiles for water diffusers & nozzles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Solve this system of differential equations.
$$ x' = y^{-2} $$

$$ y' = - \sqrt {(t+1)^2- y^{-4}} $$

x' and y' are derivatives with respect to t.

I derived this system of differential equations the other day as I was researching possible profiles for water diffusers & nozzles, used when joining pipes with different bores.

I've managed to get some numerical solutions partly graphed using the free on-line
[![Two Dimensional Differential Equation
Solver and Grapher V 1.0][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5brT.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5brT.jpg),
selecting the option 
*"System of first order DEs: x' = f(x, y, t), y' = g(x, y, t)"*
and typing in

x' = y^(-2)
y' = -1*sqrt((t+1)^2-y^(-4))
with initial values for (x,y) (0,1+)

and the profiles look to be of interest to me but they often only get **partly** graphed because of "NaN" errors recurring during a plot, presumably because this system of equations is numerically unstable with the method used there and likewise with the Euler method I used with my spreadsheet which caused (after a certain number of rows had been calculated) "ERR"s eventually when the program attempts to calculate the square root of a negative value, which ends the numerical solution right there and then, unfortunately.

So an analytical solution would be more efficient and convenient, if there is one?

## Derivation

Water is accelerated in a nozzle or a pipe of reducing width, which is rotationally symmetrical about the X-axis, with the bore, the inner diameter and the inner radius proportional to a function $ y(x)$.

Neglecting viscosity and considering averages for simplicity, the velocity of the water in the X-axis is inversely proportional to the bore's area of cross section and to $ y^2 $.

$$ x' = y^{-2} $$

The average velocity r', of a radial element, a thin slice of water "pie", is composed of the vector addition of the velocity along the X-axis x' and in the radial direction y', which are related in magnitude by Pythagoras,

$$ r'^2 = x'^2 + y'^2 $$

So

$$ y' = \sqrt{r'^2 - x'^2} $$

Under uniform acceleration $ r' = at + u $, at a time t, with acceleration a and initial velocity u, but for simplicity here, both a and u are assumed to be 1.

$$ r' = t + 1 $$

Therefore

$$ y' = - \sqrt{ (t+1)^2 - y^{-4}} $$

choosing the negative root corresponding to an radially inward y' when water accelerates in a nozzle.

## Approximate solution for $ x(0)=0,y(0)=1 $

With the initial conditions $ t=0, x=0, y=1 $ then $ x' = r' = 1 $ and $ y'=0 $.

Assuming that then $ y' << x' $ for all $ t>0 $ then approximately
$$ x' = t + 1 $$
Integrating with respect to t and substituting for t (or simplifying this equation for linear acceleration, $ x'^2 - u^2 = 2ax $ with $a=1$ and $u=1$ ) gives
$$ x'^2 - 1 = 2x $$ 
Substituting for $ x' = \sqrt{2x+1} $ in the system equation $ x' = y^{-2} $ and rearranging for y gives
$$ y = (2x+1)^{-0.25} $$
As this graph shows, this is a good approximate solution for these starting conditions.

[image: graph of $ y = (2x+1_^{-0.25} $]

## Numerical Solution

[image: Diffusers and Nozzles Profiles]

The numerical instability was managed by writing a computer program which could calculate in $t$-increments corresponding to the square root of linear increments in $ t^2 $.

$ t_{i+1} = t_i + \Delta t_i $ where $ \Delta t_i = \min(h_1,\sqrt{t_i^2+h_2}-t_i) $ and $ h_1 $, $ h_2 $ are step size constants.

Comment: No. I've got "with initial values for (x,y) (0,1+)" by which I mean x(0) = 0, y(0) is greater than or equal to 1

Comment: Well, with $y(0)=1$ and $y'<0,$ I'm not suprised that $y^{-4}$ may grow fast enough to make $(t+1)^2-y^{-4}$ negative. Are you sure your model is sound?

Comment: Sound enough to be of interest yes. Are you interested in the derivation? Gosh I haven't even got that in a presentable form. Plus as a newbie here I don't think I am allowed to post pictures so I think I won't be able to present the derivation just yet. While numerical modelling with my spreadsheet, I can get some way past the rows with ERRs by reducing the size of the increment in t and increasing greatly the number of rows before the ERRs reappear at greater values of t. The bit of the line that gets plotted looks to be exactly where it should be according to the modelling.

Comment: So you think a solution extending to $t\rightarrow\infty$ should exist, there is no physical reason for a breakdown at finite time, it's just due to numerical instability?

Comment: Well t at infinity would mean the water flowing infinitely fast in a pipe of bore zero, so I wouldn't claim that represents a "solution" but at some large finite t there's always a continuity of the model. I think the problem is just due to numerical instability, yes.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Edited to add derivation and image of graph from Two Dimensional Differential Equation Solver and Grapher V 1.0.

Comment: That graph isn't possible, different solutions can't intersect (a solution starting at the intersection point wouldn't be unique). So the "solution" must be highly inaccurate already there.

Comment: Then, I must have misinterpreted the graph. I was under the impression that all solutions start at $t=0$, just with different values of $y(0)$ (1,2,3,4). And if two intersect, like the red and the blue at $t\approx0.5$ and the same value of $y(t),$ that should give the same value of $y'(t),$ due to the differential equation, but the slopes of the red and the blue curve differ visibly at the intersection point.

Comment: @ProfessorVector The graphs are possible because the values of t are different at the intersections for the different solutions. In the intersection shown in my image between the red line, y(0)=1 and the blue line, y(0)=2, I don't believe there is any solution for t=0. However, starting from the same intersection point with a different value of t, t=0.5, say, would give a different solution.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Ah, the red and blue line intersect at x=0.5, the horizontal axis is X, vertical is Y. There is no "t" axis. At the intersection, the red and blue lines have quite different values of t, red about t=0.42 and blue about t=0.87

Comment: @ProfessorVector the slopes differ at the intersection because y'(t) differs because t differs

Comment: Ah, I see, so that's the $x$-axis, not $t$. I tried it with my own lib, but failed miserably: it uses Taylor series, which perform poorly around singularities, and that stuff in the square root _does_ get close to zero!

Comment: @ProfessorVector Numerical solution!

Comment: Meaning you used a variable step size? That makes sense.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yup. $ t_{i+1} = t_i + \Delta t_i $ where $ \Delta t_i = \min(h_1,\sqrt{t_i^2+h_2}-t_i) $ and $ h_1 $, $ h_2 $ are step size constants.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, it's just too long for a comment: a try to get the picture not from a mathematical point of view (I've told you I'm not surprised that the function under the root sign might become zero or negative), but from a physical one. I try to understand your model. And I'm not a physicist, so don't laugh too hard, please.
So you say $y$ is the varying radius of a pipe, but then, it should be a known function. If it's not known, I assume it's the free surface of a jet of water after it gets out of an orifice with initial velocity $u$. And it's accelerated even after that... ok, think of a shower, $a=g$. Now I know from my experience (in a shower, say) that the individual jets of water disintegrate into droplets after finite time. And if the initial velocity be big enough, we can't blame that entirely on the surface tension not accounted for in your model, that would be another order of magnitude, energy-wise.
So that's the picture I get, I may be dead wrong. The numerical instabilities depend heavily on the step size, so they may be artifacts, entirely. But I think they indicate a real, physical singularity, the collapse of a jet into droplets.